# collect flow based on other data

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room

Here my code

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AppRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {
    var result : ...
    var type by mutableStateOf(Type.Big)
        private set 
    
    fun updateType(type : Type){
      ...}

init{
  result = repository.getDataByType(type)
 }
```

I have room query returning a flow that I would like to call whenever type changes.
`result` is collected on the UI, preferably with something such as `collectAsStateWithLifecycle`
What is the best way to achieve this? I don't really want a StateFlow with Loading and Success as you might see in many examples.
Type will be change on the UI. I am using jetpack compose